# Change System time cause OpenVPN remove the Address of tap0

Tags: datetime, tcp, openvpn

I have connected to an openvpn server.(with --proto tcp,  --dev tap, ...) on a linux client.
Connection works well unless I change the system time like `system("/bin/date -s xxx")` and then `send(anything)` to server immediately, the tap0 node sometimes will be removed, netlink monitor will receive a `RTM_DELADDR`, if_name is `tap0`, which means its ipaddress has been deleted.

What I have tried:

1. after connected, change sys time on terminal(`/bin/date -s xxx`) then `send(anything)` to server. Cannot reproduce
2. after connected, call like below, Cannot reproduce.

```
    system("/bin/date -s xxx");
    sleep(1);//sleep 1s
    send(anything);
```

3. after connected, call like below, Can reproduce sometimes.

```
    system("/bin/date -s xxx");
    //sleep(1);//sleep 1s
    send(anything);
```

4. try to use different version of openvpn, get the same result.

We don't see any information about deleting this node in our local log file.
So my questions are:

1. Did the openvpn server delete this node or any others(like tcp proto or drivers)?
2. Why it delete it?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After catch the log of openvpn, there is a ping check timeout error, and then call the command: `/sbin/ifconfig tap0 0.0.0.0"`

The ping check function was called in the main loop of openvpn, and if there is something sent, it will be called.

The ping check function use 2 variable, `last` and `now`, both of them was get from `time(NULL)` or `gettimeofday()`, which depends on the system time, if the `last` was get before the time resetting and `now` was get after it, then(if the D-value between now and last is too large) will cause a timeout error.

That make sense, so you can't change the system time of at least Linux at will